# How do you make a web app that send out emails based on upcoming dates in a web server using php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, email

I am making a simple invoicing web application using PHP and MySQL. But I need to somehow send out an email 2 days before the due date (as specified in my database) to the user (whose email is in the database), even while the web page has no client on there. 
I'm sorry if this isn't very specific, I will attach an image to try and help you understand.

Cheers!

[image: Application Flow Image]

Comment: You can use cron job for php...

Comment: @BuggyParadox, Is this simple to implement? I am a beginner web designer!

Comment: Not quite simple, you need to be a php developer for that...

Comment: @BuggyParadox, are there any really simple ways for the dumb ones like myself?

Comment: See this article, it'll help you make it...
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/schedule-cron-jobs-in-php/

Comment: @BuggyParadox, are you sure?

Comment: Yea sure...It'll help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a cronjob;

You need:

1. Server Access
2. Linux/Mac Server

`sudo crontab -e` to open the crontab

Insert:

```
* * 1 * * php /path/to/file.php
```

That will run your file every day. Just make file.php do what you want it to do.